# Retrieving model attribute from table+column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say you have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :author
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Let's say User has an attribute name, is there any way in Ruby/Rails to access it using the table name and column, similar to what you enter in a select or where query?
Something like:

```
Comment.includes(:author).first.send("users.name")
# or
Comment.first.send("comments.id")
```

**Edit:** What I'm trying to achieve is accessing a model object's attribute using a **string**. For simple cases I can just use **object.send attribute_name** but this does not work when accessing "nested" attributes such as **Comment.author.name**.

Basically I want to retrieve model attributes using the sql-like syntax used by ActiveRecord in the where() and select() methods, so for example:

```
c = Comment.first
c.select("users.name") # should return the same as c.author.name
```

**Edit 2:** Even more precisely, I want to solve the following problem:

```
obj = ANY_MODEL_OBJECT_HERE

# Extract the given columns from the object
columns = ["comments.id", "users.name"]
```

Comment: Doesn't `Comment.first.id` work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. I see that you are using polymorphic associations, do you need to access `comment.user.name` while having `has_many :comments, :as => :author` in your `User` model?

For you polymorphic association, you should have

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And if you want to access `comment.user.name`, you can also have

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :author
  has_many :comments
end
```

Please be more specific about your goal.

Comment: edited, hope I made it more clear that I would like to use the sql-like query strings for accessing model attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a way to access the user from a comment.

Let `@comment` be the first comment:

`@comment = Comment.first`

To access the author, you just have to type `@comment.user` and If you need the name of that user you would do `@comment.user.name`. It's just [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

If you need the id of that comment, you would do `@comment.id`

Answer (score 0):

Because `user` and `id` are just methods, you can call them like that:

```
comments.send('user').send('id')
```

Or, you can build your query anyway you like:

```
Comment.includes(:users).where("#{User::columns[1]} = ?", @some_name)
```

But it seems like you're not doing thinks really Rails Way. I guess you have your reasons.